# Scheme function using association lists and Mapping

Tags: dictionary, recursion, lambda, scheme, map-function

I'm trying to create a function in scheme that's called allAssociation. It takes in 2 parameters, a list of symbols and an assoc-list. Calling this function should return a list of data with elements that correspond to the keys of the assoc-list.

Here is an example:

Input:

```
(allAssociation '(a c d) '((a allen)(b bob)(c (carl cooper))(d doug)))
```

Output:

```
(allen (carl cooper) doug).
```

I am trying to use map and lambda to implement this function, but I am a little stumped.

Currently I have this snippet of code:

```
(define AllAssociation
  (lambda (key alist)
    (if (null? alist)
        '()
        [insert rest of logic]
           )))
```

But I am struggling with implementing the logic of using map to match up each of the elements of the key with the association list. Any help would be much appreciated, for I am very new to scheme. Thank you.

Comment: For each element e in the first list, you want to get the value associated with e in the second list. You could invoke `map` on the first list with a function that searches in the second one with `assoc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you iterate over the `keys` list, and use `assoc` to retrieve the first matching element in list `lst`.

If you need to use `map` (as your text suggests), then something like this will do:

```
(define all-association
    (lambda (keys lst)
      (map (lambda (key) (cadr (assoc key lst)))
           keys)))
```

If you have to do it without `map` (as your code suggests), the equivalent would be:

```
(define all-association
  (lambda (keys lst)
    (if (null? keys)
        '()
        (cons (cadr (assoc (car keys) lst))
              (all-association (cdr keys) lst)))))
```

Testing:

```
> (all-association '(a c d) '((a allen)(b bob)(c (carl cooper))(d doug)))
'(allen (carl cooper) doug)
```